# Managing arrays - mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to populate existing array with other array:

```
if (!self.photos){
    self.photos = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
} else {
    NSArray *newPhotosFromFeed = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
    [self.photos addObjectsFromArray:newPhotosFromFeed];
}
```

Compiler throw me an error - `mutating method sent to immutable object` .

Photos declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *photos;
```

Method declaration (from Apple.developer) is following:

```
- (void)addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray
```

So, how am i violate the rules?

I add **NON-mutable** array `NSArray *newPhotosFromFeed` to **MUTABLE** array `self.photos`.

So why am i get that error??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this line is called first:

```
self.photos = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
```

then you will be storing an immutable array in a mutable property. The compiler can't tell it's wrong and the runtime doesn't check so you don't know it's happening. Then, later, when you call:

```
[self.photos addObjectsFromArray:newPhotosFromFeed];
```

you get the crash.

So, you should always ensure that the object being set to `photos` is mutable, the easiest way it by taking the `mutableCopy` as that will work on both mutable and immutable source objects:

```
self.photos = [[responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: thank you but I'm still not understand it, i mean i declared photos as mutable array, that type is constant isn't it?

Comment: The type tells the compiler what to expect, that is all. You can create a property as an `NSArray *` and then do `self.prop = (NSArray *)[[NSObject alloc] init]` if you want to, because you're telling the compiler to believe you. It won't work when you later try to use the object as an array, because it isn't one, but you can store whatever you want in the property...

Comment: what you want to say is, when I'm assigning self.photos to [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"];, i basically changing it type to an NSArray?

Comment: No, you "promised" to the compiler that you will be assigning a mutable array to your property which is of type NSMutableArray* . However in runtime, you actually assigned an immutable array to that property and then tried to mutate this array which is not possible. The property is a reference pointer; it simply points to something. It's your fault that you pointed it to an object of wrong type. That object then naturally cannot respond to selector with name @"addObjectsFromArray:".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix :

```
self.photos = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"].mutableCopy;
```

and

```
NSArray *newPhotosFromFeed = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"].mutableCopy;
```

You're attempting to set an `NSMutableArray` to a `NSArray`. That doesn't work without using `mutableCopy`. Use `mutableCopy` to create a mutable copy of the `NSArray` and that object becomes an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: `newPhotosFromFeed` doesn't need to be mutable, the OP is correct that adding that immutable array to a mutable array is fine.